# How to use where and group by conditions with cakephp2?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to cakephp2 and I wanted to ask you a little favor.I'm currently learning cakephp2 but I'm having some hard time trying to understand how to use where and groupby clause in cakephp2.
I am tring to convert this sql query below to cakphp2 but how will I do it using find() ?

```
select  params,count(params) from pv_logs
where  dt = '2014/9/25' and is_crawler = 0
group by params order by  count(params) desc limit 100 ;
```

This is how I did it in cakephp2 format but do you see something wrong with this ?

```
  $pvcount = $this->PvLog->find('all', array(
          'fields' => array('dt','params','count(params)'),
          'conditions'=>array('PvLog.dt'=>'2014/9/25','PvLog.is_crawler'=>0),
          'group'=>array('PvLog.params'),
          'order'=>array('PvLog.count(params)'),
          'limit' => 100,
          ));
```

Comment: Have you *not* read the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I did read the documentation and tried to convert the query above to cakephp2 standard, however, it does not work.

Comment: You'll need to show us what you tried. This isn't Cake syntax, it's just standard SQL. It's all in the docs, just base yourself on the examples.

Comment: I've added the cakephp2 version of the query but do you see something wrong with this code?

Comment: Is your code is not working?

Comment: If your debug level is > 0, then it should tell you what the problem is, with the SQL statement it attempted to use.

Comment: I feel that the cakphp2 query is not wrong, however,It's not working .I simply want to run the normal sql query in cakephp2 but how can I do it?

Comment: `$this->PvLog->query('...')` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

Comment: `'order'=>array('PvLog.count(params)'),` looks like it should really be `'order'=>array('count(PvLog.params)'),` at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below

```
 $this->PvLog->virtualFields['params_count']='count(params)';
 $pvcount = $this->PvLog->find('all', array(
      'fields' => array('dt','params','params_count'),
      'conditions'=>array('PvLog.dt'=>'2014-09-25','PvLog.is_crawler'=>0),
      'group'=>array('PvLog.params'),
      'order'=>array('params_count'=>'asc'),
      'limit' => 100,
      ));
```